# Summarise rows in dataframe by two columns

Tags: r

I have this data frame called `World`which shows the following:

```
City           Year           Income           Tourist
London         2008             50               100
NY             2009             75               250
Paris          2010             45               340
Dubai          2008             32               240
London         2011             50               140
Abu Dhabi      2009             60               120
Paris          2009             70               140
NY             2007             50               150
Tokyo          2008             45               150
Dubai          2010             40               480
#With 207 more rows
```

I want to summarise each rows so that every city shows the total income and tourists for all the years. So I want to find a code where City and Years are matched and then summarised so that every city just have one row.

Something like this:

```
City          Income            Tourist
London         1051              5040
NY             1547              5432
Paris          2600              4321
Dubai          3222              5312
Abu Dhabi      3100              7654
Tokyo          2404              4321
#With 40 more rows
```

After the research I've done `n_distinct` and `group_by` should be used.

Comment: You're on the right lines.  What did you try and why didn't it work?

Comment: ```group_by(City) %>%
summarise(count = n_distinct(Year))```

Comment: However it doesn't work for me. @Limey

Comment: `count` counts rows.  `sum` sums values.  Keep at it.  Bear in mind that "it didn't work" isn't very informative.  In what way didn't it work?  Did you get an error message?  Did you get output that didn't meet your expectation?  We need clarity.

Comment: My tibble unfortunately looks strange. Count just shows how many years there are n says how many times the City are matching with a year. Hmm. @Limey

Comment: I suppose I need to mention ```Income```and ```Tourist``` in the code so it will be included in the tibble.

Comment: "My tibble looks strange" is equally uninformative.  So we know `n()` and `count()` don't give you what you want.  Have you tried `sum()` yet?  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will help you ask a great question.

Comment: Thanks for your advice @Limey . I'll try to solve my task and then post an answer in this thread.

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution:

You can use the **sapply()** function to iterate over cities.

- the first argument will be a vector of unique cities
- we then write our function that select all the rows (years) of each city and returns the "Income" and "Tourist" columns
- Sum the columns values with **colSums()** function
- Transpose the output using the **t()** function.

```
t( sapply( unique( World$City ),function(CITY) colSums(World[World$City==CITY,c("Income","Tourist")] ) ) )
```

Solution with R's data.table package:

- Make sure your object is of type data.table.
- in the j part of the bracket (the ***do*** part):
  you can provide names to the wanted columns ("Income="),
  and specify the wanted output ("sum(Income)").
- To group the cities, add a **by** argument to the data.table object.

```
World[,.(Income=sum(Income),Tourist=sum(Tourist)),by=City]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can use group_by and summarise function.

```
world %>% group_by(City) %>% summarise(across(c(Income,Tourist), sum))
```

you can also add Year in the group by function.

```
world %>% group_by(City,Year) %>% summarise(across(c(Income,Tourist), sum))
```